# Cannot resolve symbol ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was trying to implement a `recycler view`. but i am not able to use `viewHolder`. Please find a solution. Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: share your code with question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Comment: You need to create the class of **`viewHolder`** in Your Adapter class

Comment: create the `ViewHolder` class in the adapter class in the screenshot. Then use the class `com.example.user.rockytravels.RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter.ViewHolder`.

Comment: `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` not `RecyclerView.Adapter.ViewHolder`

Answer (score 6):

You can try this way hope so it will be helpful for you.

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

            private List<String> myList;

            public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public TextView title, year, genre;

                public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
                    year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
                }
            }


            public YourAdapter(List<String> list) {
                this.myList = list;
            }

            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

                return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                Movie movie = myList.get(position);
                holder.title.setText(myList.get(position).getTitle());

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return myList.size();
            }
        }
```

Comment: refer this example you will get clear understanding link https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 3):

Try to use just `ViewHolder` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter.ViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

...
```

And make sure you have a ViewHolder class inside your adapter class:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a new **Class** inside your **Adapter** **Class** like bellow :

```
public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;
    public ImageView imageView;


    public viewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    }
}
```