# How to set target viewholder for picasso in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm using Picasso Library in Custom RecyclerView adapter. In onBindViewHolder(), binding to view holder is showing error

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView image_view;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            image_view = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.background);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int 
    listPosition)
    {
        String abcd = "http://localhost/tack/poster1.jpg";
        Picasso.with((Context) mContext).load(abcd).into(holder.image_view);
    }
```

Showing Error - `cannot resolve symbol 'image_view'`

I need to bind the image from URL to ImageView

Comment: Hello. I have a Class, but I use Glide instead of Picasso. Do you want?

Comment: Both picasso and glide  needs the viewholder to set image. I can't access the viewholder

Comment: You need to cast `ViewHolder` into Your inner `ViewHolder` OR Just change type in adapter like `YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder >`

Comment: @ADM  Sorry, can you please be more specific. What's inner ViewHolder in above code ?

Comment: I was specific ..  Just let your Adapter class `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder>` .. and implement methods with parameter `YourAdapter.ViewHolder`..follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/47730481/4168607.

Comment: @ADM. Thanks That's Working Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at my adapter and compare it with yours and then update the required methods and parameters as you need.

```
public class FollowerAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowerAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    public FollowerAdapter1(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_followers,null);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final MyViewHolder holder, final int i) {
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load("YOUR IMAGE URL")
                        .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.placeholder))
                        .into(holder.ivfollower);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return 10;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView ivfollower,ivfollow;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivfollower=itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_follow_profile);

        }
    }
}
```